# How to go to next file if a file does not exist using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code for opening ascii files. How to skip a file that does not exist in the directory maindir1?

```
val1=["M1","M2"]
val2=["D1","D2","D3"]

for iis,ival1 in enumerate(val1):
       for jjs, ival2 in enumerate(val2):
            df1 = pd.read_csv(maindir1+str(ival1)+str(ival2)+".txt", sep="\t", header=None)
            df2 = pd.read_csv(maindir1+str(ival1)+str(ival2)+".txt", sep="\t", header=None)
```

Comment: chech file path exist using `os.path.exist(filepath)`, after that read in dataframe

Comment: you are not using `/` in your file paths. is that intended?

Comment: Typically better to use a `try/except` block when immediately opening a file. You should wrap the `read_csv` call lines in `try: ... except: FileNotFoundError`, where you can handle the error, or just `pass` to skip the files which don't exist.